# Is "What is on on TV" correct?

Tags: prepositions, phrases

I am from Poland and my private teacher said that the phrase "What is on TV?" is grammatically incorrect and she told me about phrase "What is on on TV?" which is according to her grammatically correct.

I would like to know which phrase is correct because as I ask my English friends they say that first one is valid and I am little confused.

Comment: If you want to blow his mind, show him this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sShMA85pv8M

Comment: In fact *What's on TV?* is the most common expression. *What is on TV?* is also correct. The other one is absolutely incorrect; no native English speaker says that in unironic everyday English.

Comment: I can, but I've already explained it below. I agree the “rule” is somewhat unnecessary, but sacking somebody for *one* opinion you disagree with seems like what [interpersonal.se] would call *the nuclear option*.

Comment: @AndyT I believe that I can just about remember a time when some people said "What's on on TV?" or "What's on on the radio" with a slight pause betweeen the two 'ons'. The logic behind it is that it has the same structure as "What's on at the theatre (or cinema)", which can certainly be parsed. I haven't heard it for decades and I've certainly never used it as an adult so the tutor is guilty of confusing the OP with outdated English and gross pedantry. The form did exist but I don't believe anyone uses it any more.

Comment: @WillCrawford - True, it's a nuclear option. I don't feel quite so strongly about it any more. I'll retract.

Comment: What's on, on [ON TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONTV_(pay_TV))?

Comment: @Clare - Editing the OP's question to correct their English is good practice. Teaching the OP English *within his question* is not good practice. If you want to tell the OP what grammatical options they have, do it in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is, to put it mildly, much more common and idiomatic.

It *is* the source of a popular children's joke:

> Q: What's on the television tonight, Dad?
>   A: Same as usual, Son — the goldfish bowl and some flowers!

The “corrected” version is based on the notion that the first *on* is what’s currently being broadcast, and the second is describing where it appears. It's not helpful, but at least preempts the aforementioned silly joke.

For those who perceive it as mere tautology, the *first* “on” means *playing*, as in *What's on at the theatre tonight?*, or *happening*, or *up*. The second is about the presence of the image on the screen.

It’s not that the teacher is *grammatically incorrect*, simply that ***[almost](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbc7/comedy/progpages/seriousaboutcomedy1.shtml)* [no-one](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g188590-d229149-r513235018-WestCord_City_Centre_Hotel_Amsterdam-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html)** says it that way **[any more](https://www.englishforums.com/English/OnChannel4/nlkbh/post.htm)**.

Comment: We might need to explain to younger readers that old CRT TVs stood on the floor and were wide enough to put things on - if you’ve only ever known wall mounted flat screens, that joke makes no sense at all ;-)

Comment: @JonLarby that might explain why I was unable to find a citation for the joke after fifteen minutes with Google(!) :o)

Comment: "the notion that the first on is what’s currently being broadcast, and the second is describing where it appears." Sorry, but this doesn't work for me as an explanation at all!

Comment: How would you parse the "on" in "what's on at the theatre?" then?

Comment: @peterG - It took me a while to get it, but Will is right. Try inserting "at 8pm" into the sentence. The only way to then make it work is to have two **on**s: "*What's **on** at 8pm **on** TV?*". Idiomatitcally of course we'd rephrase this to "What's on TV at 8pm?" but there's no grammatical reason not to put "at 8pm" first.

Comment: *No one* ever asks "What is on on the radio/TV" Please find one reference where this usage was even remotely used in the past. See Google search results for ["what is on on TV"](https://www.google.com/search?ei=jdWHWuDYHcKMmgWZ_KyAAw&q=%22what+is+on+on+tv%22+&oq=%22what+is+on+on+tv%22+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l4j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l4.3705.4855.0.5684.7.7.0.0.0.0.171.1174.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.1172....0.IXAh0cFKZM4) Ergo, the teacher's phrase is indeed grammatically incorrect.

Comment: [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbc7/comedy/progpages/seriousaboutcomedy1.shtml) which is one of the first hits if you change your search to ["what's on on tv"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="what%27s+on+on+tv") ... there are a handful of other hits, which tends to support my assertion that ***almost no one** says it that way*.

Comment: Not finding something on Google doesn't actually imply that it's grammatically incorrect. It just waggles its eyebrows suggestively while mouthing the words *on on TV*.

Comment: I agree that no one would say "**What is** on on TV", though ;o)

Comment: Perhaps someone could update [Darrell Huff’s masterpiece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Lie_with_Statistics) and call it *How to lie with search results* ... ;o)

Comment: I actually have no trouble imagining "What's on on TV?"  It sounds fine to me.  I probably wouldn't *write* it, though.

Answer (score 1):

"What's on TV?" is better, because "What's on?" means "What's on TV?", and if "What's on on TV" were acceptable, it would mean "What's on TV on TV?", which is ungrammatical.

Comment: Not really, the first “on” does mean something *slightly* different. Like "What's on at the theatre”, the first means “[What’s] happening” or “[What’s] playing".

Comment: @WillCrawford, I agree that if "What's on on TV?" were grammatical, the first "on" would have to be given a different interpretation such as the one you describe.